# HtmlHelper on type parameter of generic view-model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, generics, viewmodel, html-helper

I'm trying to create an HtmlHelper method on a strongly-typed view, where the view-model is a generic.  But there's a complication.  I want to simplify my syntax so I can specify a member expression of a property on my view-model.  Consider the following.

```
public interface ViewModel<T>
{
    T Model { get; set; }
}

public class DocViewModel : ViewModel<Document> 
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Options { get; set; }
    public Document Model { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I can easily create a helper that references the view-model itself, and use it like so:

```
@model DocViewModel
<div>
    @Html.DoSomething(vm => vm.Options);
    @Html.DoSomethingElse(vm => vm.Model.Name);
    @Html.DoSomethingYetAgain(vm => vm.Model.Value);
</div>
```

But I'd like to be able to pass simply an expression on the Model, like so:

```
@model DocViewModel
<div>
    @Html.DoSomething(vm => vm.Options);
    @Html.DoSomethingElse(vm => vm.Name);
    @Html.DoSomethingYetAgain(vm => vm.Value);
</div>
```

Now, I can write the helper in such a way that I can do this if I explicitly reference the type parameters in my calls:

```
@model DocViewModel
<div>
     @Html.DoSomething<Document>(vm => vm.Name);
</div>
```

But that sort of defeats the purpose of what I'm going after.  It seems like I should be able to write an HtmlHelper that can exploit the fact that the view is strongly-typed on DocViewModel, which itself is a ViewModel, and that @Html() returns

```
HtmlHelper<DocViewModel> //HtmlHelper<ViewModel<Document>>
```

so that the type-param that Document represents is known implicitly, and so that I can write

```
public static string DoSomethingElse<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<ViewModel<TModel>> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) 
{
    return "Whatever";
}
```

but that conversion can't be done.  So is there any way I can do this?  Or am I just going to have to live with the ugly syntax?

Edit: Changed incorrect references to "KoViewModel" to "ViewModel"

Edit again:  Also, the point of making ViewModel generic is so that I can declare any other type of ViewModel:

```
public class ProgramViewModel : ViewModel<Program>
{
    //other stuff
    public Program Model { get; set; }
}
public class Program
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
    //other properties I want to reference
}
```

and in another view:

```
@model ProgramViewModel
<div>
    @Html.DoSomethingElse(vm => vm.Something)
</div>
```

Again, I'd like to be able to dereference properties on both the view's view-model, as well as the view-model's Model property, without having to explicitly reference types in my method calls.

The problem with the method I have defined above is that there can apparently be no implicit conversion between HtmlHelper and HtmlHelper, so that the compiler cannot resolve the @Html call in the view as the one above (" does not contain a definition for  and no extension method blah blah blah").  Explicit casts all around would make that work, certainly, but that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: you have to specify the Type ``<T>`` as your are using generics

Comment: Specify <T> on what?  The view is of type WebViewPage<DocViewModel>.  DocViewModel is KoViewModel<Document>, so I would think there's a way to implicitly resolve T as Document.

Comment: I suspect it can't figure out type of `TProperty`. Usually second level of generics help in such case  something like `Html.DoSomthingForModel().ForProperty(vm -> vm.Name)`... Exact error could help diagnose the issue (standalone sample that does not rely on custom classes would be nice too).

Answer (score 0):

If you can change ViewModel to an abstract class do the following:

```
public abstract class ViewModel<TModel>
{
    public class HtmlHelper : HtmlHelper<ViewModel<TModel>> {}
    public TModel Model;
}
```

Then write the following static extension method:

```
public static TProperty DoSomethingElse<TModel, TProperty>(this ViewModel<TModel>.HtmlHelper helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) 
{
    return default(TProperty);
}
```

This should implicitly resolve.

Comment: Sorry, "KoViewModel" references should read "ViewModel".  Edited.

Comment: Ah, ok.  that changes it a bit.  I'll post an update.

Comment: I've posted an update.  If you are unable to change ViewModel to an abstract, you will either need to use VB.Net or IL to nest the HtmlHelper class within the ViewModel interface, since C# does not allow nesting of types within interfaces, but the CLR and VB.Net do.

Comment: Note that you will need to use an instance of the new nested HtmlHelper instead of the original one in order for this to work.

Comment: Okay, that resolves implicitly when I manually instantiate the nested helper in the view: @{ var h = new DocViewModel(Html..ViewContext, Html.ViewDataContainer); } @h.DoSomethingElse(vm => vm.Name).  But is there going to be a way to resolve the HtmlHelper of the desired types in my different views without manually instantiating it in every one?

Comment: how do you normally obtain an instance of it?

Comment: Well, I've never gone into the deep innards of MVC, but a strongly-typed view apparently has a WebViewPage<T> class underlying it where T is the ViewModel.  So when referencing @Html in the Razor view, it's calling a WebVIewPage<T>.Html property that gets the HtmlHelper<T>, all of which has been instantiated by the framework.  It looks like I could use the solution here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx/ in order to define a new property to get the helper.  But I don't know if I want every view to have this...just the ones with a VM typed as above.

Comment: Based on the content of that article, you may be able to use a location tag in the web.config coupled with a subfolder to use a CustomWebPageView as the base class only for views located within that sub folder.  Then you would place all of the views that follow this new pattern that you are developing into that subfolder and gain the new version of the helper from there.